# Parsing deep XML with PHP SimpleXML and XPath

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

PHP noob here. I seem to be misunderstanding how to get the value of an XML node using XPath, and I haven't been able to find a StackOverflow answer that quite address what I'm doing wrong.

So, using RPG Geek's API, I'm trying to pull some information about the game *Dread*. ([Here's a link to the URI](https://www.rpggeek.com/xmlapi/boardgame/43850?&stats=1).)

```
$rpggeekXML = simplexml_load_file('https://www.rpggeek.com/xmlapi/boardgame/166952?&stats=1');
$rating = $rpggeekXML->xpath('ratings/average');
$usersrated = $rpggeekXML->xpath('ratings/usersrated');
```

I know I'm successfully pulling in the rpggeek XML because if I do `var_dump($rpggeekXML);`, I can see all of the information I'm expecting. However, if I do `var_dump($rating);` or `var_dump($usersrated);`, it returns `array(0) { }`. So it seems I must be screwing up the XPath lines, but I can't figure out how. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use full path to find desired node:

```
$rating = $rpggeekXML->xpath( 'boardgame/statistics/ratings/average' );

echo $rating[0];
```

Collect all `"average"` nodes in document:

```
$rating = $rpggeekXML->xpath( '//average' );    

echo $rating[0];
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, and I see now where I was misunderstanding things. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you xpath syntax is wrong. You can try this

```
$rpggeekXML = simplexml_load_file('https://www.rpggeek.com/xmlapi/boardgame/166952?&stats=1');
$rating = $rpggeekXML->xpath('//ratings/average');
$usersrated = $rpggeekXML->xpath('//ratings/usersrated');
```